# How would I make a custom physicsBody for this shape I have?

Tags: swift, skphysicsbody

I have these 5 rectangles that are different sizes and separate by half an inch and I want to wrap a physics body around these rectangles but the only way I know how to do it is by using bodyOfRectangle, and circleOfRadius.

How do I make a custom physics body so the physics body wraps around each size of the rectangles evenly?

This is how I did it but each rectangles dont have there own size its just one big rectangle wrapped around it.

```
fiveRectangles.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: fiveRectangles.size)
```

Comment: don't pass hints. Post your full question with your codes. Thank you

Comment: I don't really have any code because I don't know how to make a custom physics body that will wrap around different size rectangles.

Comment: `If you need more info please let me know.` ????

Comment: I meant if you didn't understand the question.